# How to select all elements except all <p> elements and all their children using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to use a javascript dom selector method like `getElementsByTagName` to select all elements except all `<p>` elements and all their children and I'll be using this for some specific scraping requirements in certain webpages.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll('*:not(p, p *)')
```

the `:not(..)`-pseudo-selector will exclude elements matching the selector in parenthesis.

Also see [Mozilla documentation of :not()-pseudoselector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work in my Chrome console but in my headless chromium where Im running a script, I get the error `DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '*:not(p, p *)' is not a valid selector.` It could be something I did wrong, but let me know if you know about this

Answer (score 0):

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('*'); // Selects all elements
let filteredElements = []; // array only with needed elements

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i].tagName !== 'P' && !elements[i].matches('p  *')) {
    filteredElements.push(elements[i]); // Checks if processed element is not <p> or a child of it on any depth level
  }
}
```

A code like this should do the job. Lines are self-explanatory pretty much, but I added some comments there.

Comment: The op asked for a selector, not for a programmatic way of filtering.

Comment: Sorry, I dont't know what deletion you are talking about. Seems like we understood the question in a different way. My comment was not meant to offend you. I'm sorry if it seemed to you like this.

Comment: Maybe someone with enough reputation can bring clearity to this and review the deleted posts. I don't know what happened in this thread before. I edited my answer especially regarding the reference, but I did not delete anything..

Comment: The answer which was deleted was by a different user and I believe it was wrong as it did not consider children of `<p>` tags . I'm okay with this programmatic approach and will upvote it once I test. Thanks